# UML designer with python export?

Tags: windows-7, osx, python, uml

I want to design a complex software but develop it later with Python (/Django). For this reasons I want to use a uml designer to create my class diagram. But neither MS Vision, nor Dia nor yEd have any python/django class export.

Does such a software exist?

Answer (score 2):

There is [BOUML](http://www.bouml.fr/) *free to version 4.23.7* which boasts:

- UML2
- Generate code under

  - C++,
  - Java,
  - Idl,
  - Php,
  - Python and
  - MySQL.
- Round trip, Code->UML->Code for C++ and java
- Runs on Windows, Linux & OS-X **but you pay for each**

Answer (score 0):

For a free tool that can model in UML and generate diagrams from code I would suggest taking a look at [Umbrello](https://umbrello.kde.org/):

- UML 1.4 & 2.0
- Generate Code in:

  - ActionScript
  - Ada
  - C++
  - C#
  - D
  - IDL
  - Java
  - JavaScript
  - MySQL
  - Pascal
  - Perl
  - PHP
  - PHP5
  - PostgreSQL
  - **Python**
  - Ruby
  - SQL
  - Tcl
  - Vala
  - XMLSchema
- Code Import from:

  - Ada
  - C++
  - C#
  - IDL
  - Java
  - Pascal
  - **Python**
  - More
- It is free & Open Source
- Runs under Linux (KDE) and Windows

Answer (score 0):

If this is an enterprise project, You could use [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/products/ea/index.html).
It's a complete suite for software modeling. It can also export UML/ER Diagram in Python language.